# What is the logic behind the Emacs keybinding scheme?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, emacs

I'm just starting to use Emacs. I'm having a hard time remembering the keyboard commands. Maybe there is some system to it that I haven't noticed yet?

Why do some things use Meta and some Control? 
Why is split window C-x 2?

Comment: It is as it is, <Ctrl> gives control and <Meta> is meta-ish. Why something is as it is is subjective, you should consult the Emacs manual and developers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the SO question ["Learning emacs - useful mnemonics"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677300/learning-emacs-useful-mnemonics), and I'll point out [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677300/learning-emacs-useful-mnemonics/2679400#2679400) which points out patterns in the key bindings.